# How do i use procedure to insert/update multi record of Telerik:RadGrid batch editing mod?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, batch-processing

I'm newbie on Telerik and trying to use RadGrid with that form:

```
    <telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True"
        AllowAutomaticInserts="True" PageSize="10" OnItemDeleted="RadGrid1_ItemDeleted" OnInsertCommand="RadGrid1_ItemInserted"
        OnItemUpdated="RadGrid1_ItemUpdated" OnPreRender="RadGrid1_PreRender" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" AllowPaging="True"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnBatchEditCommand="RadGrid1_BatchEditCommand" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="TopAndBottom" DataKeyNames="PRODUCTID"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" HorizontalAlign="NotSet" EditMode="Batch" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <BatchEditingSettings EditType="Cell" />
            <SortExpressions>
                <telerik:GridSortExpression FieldName="PRODUCTID" SortOrder="Ascending" />
            </SortExpressions>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PRODUCTID" HeaderStyle-Width="210px" HeaderText="PRODUCTID" SortExpression="PRODUCTID"
                    UniqueName="PRODUCTID" DataType="System.Decimal" FilterControlAltText="Filter PRODUCTID column" ReadOnly="True">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PRODUCTNAME" DataType="System.String" FilterControlAltText="Filter PRODUCTNAME column" HeaderText="PRODUCTNAME" SortExpression="PRODUCTNAME" UniqueName="PRODUCTNAME">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DESCRIPTION" FilterControlAltText="Filter DESCRIPTION column" HeaderText="DESCRIPTION" SortExpression="DESCRIPTION" UniqueName="DESCRIPTION">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="COLOR" FilterControlAltText="Filter COLOR column" HeaderText="COLOR" SortExpression="COLOR" UniqueName="COLOR">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="UOM" FilterControlAltText="Filter UOM column" HeaderText="UOM" SortExpression="UOM" UniqueName="UOM">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="STATUS" FilterControlAltText="Filter STATUS column" HeaderText="STATUS" SortExpression="STATUS" UniqueName="STATUS">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CREATEDBY" FilterControlAltText="Filter CREATEDBY column" HeaderText="CREATEDBY" SortExpression="CREATEDBY" UniqueName="CREATEDBY">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="LASTUPDATEDBY" FilterControlAltText="Filter LASTUPDATEDBY column" HeaderText="LASTUPDATEDBY" SortExpression="LASTUPDATEDBY" UniqueName="LASTUPDATEDBY">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridButtonColumn ConfirmText="Delete this product?" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow"
                    ConfirmTitle="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" HeaderStyle-Width="50px" ButtonType="ImageButton"
                    CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" UniqueName="DeleteColumn">
                </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
        <ClientSettings AllowKeyboardNavigation="true"></ClientSettings>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

So, how do I get value of inserted items when i click Save button in CodeBehind file ( RadGrid1_ItemInserted function ) to use stored procedure. I followed [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/batch-editing/defaultcs.aspx) to modify that code ( don't want to use SQLDatasource )
Tks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Disable the automatic CRUD operations and use the BatchEditCommand event: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-editing/edit-mode/batch-editing

IT shows how you should loop through the commands to see what's edited/added/deleted, shows how to get the values in a hash table, then you can write your SQL queries or other logic that will modify your database.